# Centrar horizontal y verticalmente elementos de una columna en Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Estoy trabajando sobre Bootstrap 4 quiero tratar de centrar horizontalmente tanto verticalmente, los elementos que están dentro de mi columna, lo he tratado de hacer con flex pero no lo logro, adjunto mi código

```css
.box-services {
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia.</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary box-services">
        <h4>Lorem</h4>
        <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 bg-secondary">
        <h4>Lorem</h4>
        <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-primary">
      <h4>Lorem</h4>
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Gracias

Comment: ¿Te refieres a los textos cierto?

Comment: Es correcto, lo trate de hacer con flex box pero el h1 se divide con el p.

Comment: ¿Dónde aplicaste flexbox exactamente?

Comment: div class="col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-primary box-services">

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Bootstrap 4 Centrar vertical y horizontalmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176854/bootstrap-4-centrar-vertical-y-horizontalmente)

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr el objetivo deseado aplicando *FlexBox* podrías que hacer lo siguiente:

- Al contenedor del título y del párrafo dale una disposición `flex`
- Usa el valor de `column` para establecer un direccionamiento vertical de los elementos, ya que inicialmente el uso de `flex` te va a colocar el `h#` junto al párrafo `p` en el eje horizontal uno a lado del otro
- Como el direccionamiento cambió, entonces usaremos:

  - `justify-content` con un valor de `center` para mover los elementos al centro de manera vertical
- Movemos al párrafo al centro con `text-center` al centro de su contenedor

Quedando así:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .elementos {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
    }
    </style>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="elementos 
                  d-flex 
                  flex-column 
                  justify-content-center 
                  text-center">
        <h3>Elemento título</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam perferendis odio 
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**Enlaces de referencia**

- [text-align](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-alignment)
- [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/)
- [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

Comment: Muchas gracias, quedo solucionado.