# ¿Como crear un formulario centrado con boostrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hola estoy tratando de crear un formulario de login a pantalla completa, la alineacion horizontal funciona muy bien pero no puedo centrarlo verticalmente, estoy utilizando bootsrap, si es posible quisiera saber como pacerlo con css tambien si no es mucha moplestia. Este es mi codigo html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center ">
    <form class="mt-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

y se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pegado, si uso los mt de bootrap si funciona pero quisiera centrarlo mejor.

Comment: centrarlo horizontal y verticalmente amigo, ahora solo lo tengo centrado horizontalmente

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Bootstrap 4 Centrar vertical y horizontalmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176854/bootstrap-4-centrar-vertical-y-horizontalmente)

Answer (score 0):

con css al row dale una altura de 100%, el problema es que no tiene espacio y por eso alineacion vertical no es visible.

```
   <div class="container-fluid border">
<div class="row border" style="height:100vh;">
  <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Es una forma facil de hacerlo.

Comment: Existen las clases `.h-100` o `.mh-100`, no es necesario, ni práctico, añadir estilos _in-line_: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/