# ¿Como centrar div o elementos centrados verticalmente?

Tags: bootstrap, css3

no soy muy bueno con el `css`, a lo cual intento centrar los elementos verticalmente dentro de lo que es un `col` de **bootstrap** he intentado con los `margin`, pero no se alinea, también con `align-content`, entre otros, un ejemplo de lo que he estado realizando, donde intento centrar los elemento de ambas columnas, pero claro las 2 llevan información diferente que puede cambiar el tamaño de los respectivos contenedores.

**Todo esto realizado en `reactjs`**

```css
.main{
padding: 0px 12px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        hsl(197, 93%, 88%),
        rgba(199, 255, 255, 0.815) 50%,
        hsl(197, 93%, 88%) 100%
    );
}

.info{
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.data{
  background-color: green;
}

.title-center{
  background-color:red;
  
}

.img{
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='main'>
  <div class="row row vh-100 justify-content-around align-items-center">
  
    <div class="col info">
      <div class='title-center'>
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>info lore</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col data" >
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <div class='img'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <div class='img'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <div class='img'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <div class='img'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='col'>
          <div class='img'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como se puede observar en mi ejemplo, estoy mostrando todo en 2 columnas.

- Columna1(izquierda): Contiene textos explicativos y posiblemente una imagen vector u otro elemento visual.
- Columna2(derecha): Contiene varios `div` los cuales son separados en en otros 2 para mostrar un conjuntos de imágenes dentro, haciendo 1 fila de 2 imágenes y otra fila de 3 imágenes.

Mi problema es que no logro hacer que se centren correctamente los textos, anteriormente existía dicho problema con los `div` azules, lo cual parece que se ha solucionado con: `vh-100 justify-content-around align-items-center`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Bootstrap 4 Centrar vertical y horizontalmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176854/bootstrap-4-centrar-vertical-y-horizontalmente)

Comment: @JheymanMejia no, ya que como puede observar en mi ejemplo separo en 2 columnas que contienen algunos otros elementos internos y no se centralizan tal cual lo necesito.
La respuesta de la pregunta usan elementos que ya fueron agregados al [example] pero aun sin lograr el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías considerar usar un container si estás usando Bootstrap, te haría las cosas más sencillas, a partir de alli, el row debe tener las clases justify-content-center y align-items-center, luego, para el texto no es necesario que crees otro div, en el mismo div class col lo puedes incluir, y para que te centre el texto usa la clase text-center.

```css
.main{
padding: 0px 12px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        hsl(197, 93%, 88%),
        rgba(199, 255, 255, 0.815) 50%,
        hsl(197, 93%, 88%) 100%
    );
}

.info{
 background-color: blue;
}

.data{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='main'>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row vh-100 justify-content-around align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto info">title e info</div>
      <div class="col-auto data" >other info</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: No utilizo el `center` por que agrega un `padding` de como `100px` en los laterales.
Tu ejemplo funciona bien si el texto esta dentro de los `col` el problema que yo tengo mas `div` dentro los cuales no se centran

Comment: Pero entonces corrige tu [mre] para que se asimile de mejor manera al tuyo. Si tienes mas div que no se centran, agregalos para poder verlos.

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta, No es que crea un padding sino que por defecto el col se coloca del tamaño máximo posible si no le configuras por eso he colocado col-auto

Comment: pido una disculpas por el tiempo y confusión, tuve que replicar lo mejor que pude lo que tengo en el `col data` y que sea lo mas simple posible. edite mi [example] para mostrar la actualización y en rojo lo que quiero centrar

Comment: Esa es la idea, sino la respuesta que realemente buscas jamás la tendrás, ahora fijate es MUY diferente de antes, asi que gracias por las modificaciones.

Comment: sin embargo el hecho de centralizar los 2 col ya es una gran ayuda, no utilicé los `col-auto` por que con un texto mucho mas largo en `<p>` pasa a la columna de arriba

Comment: entonces quieres centrar el div rojo vertical y horizontalmente y los div azules tambien?

Comment: Si, lo ideal es que todo este centralizado, que claro los `div` azules al ser varios llegara un punto en el que se irán acomodando solos gracias a bootstrap

Comment: Ok solo para estar más claro: en los div azules, deseas que una fila tenga dos div y en otra tres?

Comment: si es posible si, una fila de 2 y otra fila de 3, solo que estén separados, los textos a la izquierda y los `div` azules a la derecha, pero todo centralizado lo mejor posible, que es lo que he estado intentando lograr.